# ProgressBar not showing

Tags: android, progress-bar, android-recyclerview, android-progressbar, android-mediascanner

My Relative layout has two child Rcyclerview (Invisible) and progressbar .

**What i want is** : Oncreate of layout , recyclerview to invisible and progress bar to show until AsyncTask(getting images from SD folder) completes and recyclerview visible and progressbar invisible .

**What Happening is** : My app not showing progressbar . And after asyctask completes , my recyclerview shows up .

**XML :**

```
 <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_below="@+id/view3">

                <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:paddingTop="5dp"
                    android:divider="@null"
                    android:visibility="invisible"
                    android:id="@+id/recycler_view_cameragallery"
                    android:dividerHeight="0dp"
                    android:fadingEdge="none" />

                <ProgressBar
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/progressBar_Gallery"
                    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:padding="12dp" />
            </RelativeLayout>
```

**ActivityCode:**

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,@Nullable ViewGroup container,@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState){

        View rootView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.camera_layout,container,false);
        rootView.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
        ButterKnife.inject(this,rootView);
        init();
        initialise(rootView);
        initialiseListeners();
        listofImagesPath = new ArrayList<String>();
        new mediaScanAyscTask().executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR);}
```

**AsyncTask**

```
public class mediaScanAyscTask extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void>{

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            adapter.clearApplications();
            galleryProgressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            galleryProgressBar.getIndeterminateDrawable().setColorFilter(Color.parseColor("#ff4081"), PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
            cameraRecyclerView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
            listofImagesPath = RetriveCapturedImagePath();

            if(listofImagesPath!=null){
                adapter.addApplications(listofImagesPath);
            }
            galleryProgressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            cameraRecyclerView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
        }
    }
```

> Please help me by highlighting where i got wrong .

Comment: Try changing recycler view visiblity to gone instead of invisible

Comment: @ShashankUdupa : No , still not working

Comment: I think the progressbar is too small to see, try removing the padding="12dp" from ProgressBar

Comment: @ShashankUdupa : No this too not working . Whats happening is : this async task runs two times . 1 . oncreate and 2. On ActivityResult method of camera click . So what happening is after a click , screen goes black until all postExecution gets done .

Answer (score 15):

In my case, the emulator had the Animations turned OFF in the Developer Mode and so I could not see the progress bar.

Comment: You are a lifesaver!

Answer (score 1):

Make your layout gone rather than invisable

Comment: @young_08 in android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView set visibility to gone not invisible , Do not change visibility of ProgressBar in your xml file

Answer (score 0):

I hope this answer will help you.

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
    listofImagesPath = RetriveCapturedImagePath();
        if(listofImagesPath!=null){
            adapter.addApplications(listofImagesPath);
        }
    galleryProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    cameraRecyclerView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
}
```

Second option is remove your `ProgressBar` from `.xml` file and create programmatically.

```
class YourClassName extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean>{
    ProgressDialog dialog;  

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        dialog = new ProgressDialog(Detail_Activity.this);
        dialog.setTitle("your title");
        dialog.setMessage("your message");
        dialog.setCancelable(false);
        dialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(String... params) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean aBoolean) {
        super.onPostExecute(aBoolean);
        dialog.cancel();
    }
}
```

Comment: Try this second code which is i mention above. it will help you.

Comment: No still not working . What happening is : in debugging its showing Progressbar but when i run normally its still jot showing

Comment: can you upload screenshots. it help full to understand exact problem

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem the reason is the `ProgressBar` goes to the bottom of `RecyclerView`. You need to wrap your `RecyclerView` and `ProgressBar` in  to a `FrameLayout`.

```
<RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_below="@+id/view3">
         <FrameLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:paddingTop="5dp"
                    android:divider="@null"
                    android:visibility="invisible"
                    android:id="@+id/recycler_view_cameragallery"
                    android:dividerHeight="0dp"
                    android:fadingEdge="none" />

                <ProgressBar
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/progressBar_Gallery"
                    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:padding="12dp" />
        </FrameLayout>
  </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
Try this
<ProgressBar
    style="@android:style/Widget.ProgressBar.Horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:progress="100"
    android:id="@+id/progress"/>
```

Comment: explain your answer so user will get more clarity on it

Comment: this attribute style=?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge  give programmers limited control of the progressBar to have full control of the progressBar like android:progress="100" you new to use this attribute style="@android:style/Widget.ProgressBar.Horizontal"

Comment: Please note that [comments are temporary and could be deleted anytime](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment). If you have additional information to provide, please update your answer by clicking on the "[edit]" link under the post. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks. I will take note of that.

Comment: or style="?android:progressBarStyleHorizontal"